# add identity provider in an azure function using azure cli or rest api?

Tags: azure-functions

we use azure function app and I just realised that I can setup open-id provider, then the authentication will be handled by site and I don't really need to code anything.

This is nice for me, however is there a way to add identity provider using azure cli?

I don't see the option in the command `az functionapp`. But in `az webapp`, there is command `auth openid-connect`. Is there something similar for functionapp? If not, is there a way I can do it using a restapi?

[image]

Comment: Actually, I just tried az webapp auth openid-connect, it actually works for azure function as well

Answer (score 0):

Glad @*daxu* that you have resolved the issue yourself and thanks for providing the solution that helps the community.

> **Actually, I just tried `az webapp auth openid-connect`, it actually works for azure function as well**.

As per my understanding, Web Apps and Functions belongs to the one category i.e., Azure App Service.

Some of the CLI Commands of `az webapp` works for Azure Functions also such as:

1. `az webapp config storage-account add` - Function App mounting Share
2. `az webapp config storage-account list` - Function App Mounted File shares listing

For integrating the Authentication providers such as `Openid-Connect` to the Function Apps or Web Apps, here is the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth/openid-connect?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-auth-openid-connect-add) for the commands list.

For assigning the Managed Identity (System Assigned/User-assigned) to the Web App/Function Apps, here is the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/identity?view=azure-cli-latest) helps for the commands list and their description of usage.